# Mysql problemas em conectar a uma base de dados com o python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Bom dia,

Quando eu tento conectar o python a uma base de dados obtenho o seguinte erro

`MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'k4os'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")`

Eu estou a testar diretamente no terminal do linux então não preciso de fazer a atribuição a uma variavel e tal

o codigo é

```
import MySQLdb
MySQLdb.connect(user='k4os',passwd='#mypass#')

se alguem souber ajudar agradeço :)
```

Comment: vc resumiu ou está faltando nome do host na sua conexão (e talvez o db também)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Você não está definindo qual banco de dados (`db`) vai utilizar para a conexão. Defina assim:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
             host="localhost", 
             user="k4os", 
             passwd="#mypass#",
             db="SEU_BD"
)
```

Se mesmo assim o erro persistir e você está certo que os dados de acesso estão corretos, então problema pode ser a falta de permissão desse usuário para este banco de dados. Pode tentar corrigir desta forma:

```
GRANT all privileges on SEU_BD.* to 'k4os'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '#mypass#' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Dá um feedback aí se alguma dessas soluções deu certo pra você.

Obs: alterar o `SEU_BD` para o nome do seu banco de dados.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/k4os/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k4os/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

`Isto apareceu calculo que seja por nao ter a base de dados pronta eu apenas estava a criar ligações é esse o problema certo?`

Comment: mais uma coisa aquela segunda frase que escreveu caso seja necessario a onde é que eu a escrevo?? e que como tem ; no fim não estou a ver a onde pode ser colocada